# kotlinx JSON.stringify ignore null values

Tags: json, kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

Is there a way to ignore null values when stringify? Currently it renders as:

"field":null

it would be great if there is a way that null fields are not rendered at all - but I did not find such an option. Anyone knows how this can work?

Comment: What you are looking for is against the standard. You have an object with a variety of elements, including one named "field" (as in your example). In some cases, it just happens that this specific element was not assigned any value and hence it is `null`. This does **NOT** mean that the element had been removed from the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it's not possible, but you may want to keep track of this issue: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/58